# Redshift change user password from workbench/j

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, alter, sql-workbench-j

I have a weird problem when trying to change Redshift user password using SQL workbench/j.

Here is the command I am running:
alter user someUser password 'someNewPassword';

It returns response "ALTER USER someUser successful"

However, when I try to login with the new password it fails, while the old password still works. Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: Did you `commit` the `ALTER USER` statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! That was the issue. Stupid me!